# VS2012 Making test results appear in the Test Results window

Tags: unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-2012

From the Menu I Choose Test->Run->All Tests

I can see the results of the test run in the Test Explorer but I get nothing in the Test Results window.

How do I get my test results there?

Comment: Don't feel alone because I am in that same boat right now.

Comment: Seems like I'm stranded with you guys. :P Jokes aside, a related question - where can I find the raw test data for each test run?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Unit Test Framework has been rearchitected and will no longer generate the .trx file for you in order for the Test Results Explorer to show your test run results.  From what I gather the new Test Explorer window replaces this without having to generate files.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/750184/test-results-window-does-not-show-test-results

Comment: damn it. next you'll be telling me they messed with the pending changes window...:)

Comment: although the test explorer lets me see at a glance which tests are failing and passing and lets me re-run one of my failing tests without losing all of the other tests that were failing.

Comment: Believe me when I say that I was a big fan of the Test Results Explorer because it would maintain your code coverage when running tests after having highlight enabled.  Now you have to go to the Run... -> Analyze Code Coverage for All Tests then go to the Code Coverage Results window -> Select Code Coverage Coloring every single time you want to see your code coverage.

Comment: the test explorer window is horrible - you can't tell what is going on and what tests are being run, if any

Comment: @DevDave Use the Group By Traits feature next to the search text box at the top of the tool window. If you want to tell what tests are being run, select Outcome

Comment: So wait, they redesigned the test framework but they left the window in? Is the test results window used for anything at all now?